# keypress, ctrl+c (or some combo like that)

Tags: jquery, keypress, keydown, jquery-events

I'm trying to create shortcuts on the website I'm making. I know I can do it this way:

```
if(e.which == 17) isCtrl=true;
if(e.which == 83 && isCtrl == true) {
    alert('CTRL+S COMBO WAS PRESSED!')
    //run code for CTRL+S -- ie, save!
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

But the example below is easier and less code, but it's not a combo keypress event:

```
$(document).keypress("c",function() {
  alert("Just C was pressed..");
});
```

So I want to know if by using this second example, I could do something like:

```
$(document).keypress("ctrl+c",function() {
  alert("Ctrl+C was pressed!!");
});
```

is this possible? I've tried it and it didn't work, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Another approach (no plugin needed) is to just use [`.ctrlKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.ctrlKey) property of the [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) that gets passed in.  It indicates if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> was pressed at the time of the event, like this:

```
$(document).keypress("c",function(e) {
  if(e.ctrlKey)
    alert("Ctrl+C was pressed!!");
});
```

Comment: but there's nothing like: `.keypress("c + s",` where when i hold down c AND s it will do something? and in your code i have to press them at the exact same time, i need to hold down 1 key and press another key, i'm really just creating a menu that will pop-up when i press a certain key combo, so maybe holding down s and left clicking or whatever, something like that, not sure what key combo i'm gonna use yet.

Comment: @android.nick - not built-in with jQuery core, no, you'll need a plugin for *that*, but for ctrl, alt and shift keys, you can just use `.ctrlKey`, `.altKey` and `.shiftKey` properties.

Comment: @ravz - which part, and on which version of jQuery?  This stuff is pretty low level so it *should* be working ok.

Comment: @nick e.ctrlKey did not work with IE 8.. anyways your answer helped me. i used event.keycode to detect ctrl+c

Comment: This function will trigger when control + ANY key is pressed. `keypress` just ignores that first argument. You need to compare `e.which` to determine which key was actually pressed.

Answer (score 45):

I am a *little* late to the party but here is my part

```
$(document).on('keydown', function ( e ) {
    // You may replace `c` with whatever key you want
    if ((e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey) && ( String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase() === 'c') ) {
        console.log( "You pressed CTRL + C" );
    }
});
```

Comment: This worked for me using jQuery 1.11.2.  The accepted answer did not.

Comment: Agreed this method works better with later version of jQuery

Comment: Mac's ⌘ is e.metaKey so `(e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey) && ...` worked for me

Answer (score 7):

Try the [Jquery Hotkeys](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys) plugin instead - it'll do everything you require.

> jQuery Hotkeys is a plug-in that lets
>   you easily add and remove handlers for
>   keyboard events anywhere in your code
>   supporting almost any key combination.
>
> This plugin is based off of the plugin
>   by Tzury Bar Yochay: jQuery.hotkeys
>
> The syntax is as follows:

```
$(expression).bind(types, keys, handler); $(expression).unbind(types, handler);

$(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+a', fn);

// e.g. replace '$' sign with 'EUR'
// $('input.foo').bind('keyup', '$', function(){   
//      this.value = this.value.replace('$', 'EUR'); });
```

Comment: +1 It's not good practice to bind Ctrl+C though, or any other predefined hotkey combination. Handle with care.

Comment: agreed, it was just an example, i'm actually trying to figure out the best key combo for a menu that would pop-up by the mouse cursor.

Comment: but a plugin for what i need is just overkill, I already posted some working code in my question above, the first example. It works just fine, i'm just trying to figure out if i can do a key combo with the second example i gave. thanks though.

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't get it to work with .keypress(), but it worked with the .keydown() function like this:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.key == "c" && e.ctrlKey) {
        console.log('ctrl+c was pressed');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> by jQuery , but you can with another library which is [shortcut.js](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/55765722/delivred/abdennour/lib/js/shortcut.js)

Live Demo : 
[Abdennour JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/XvNGc/17/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
shortcut.add("Ctrl+C", function() {
    $('span').html("أحسنت. لقد ضغطت على حرفي : Ctrl+C");
        });
    shortcut.add("Ctrl+V", function() {
    $('span').html("أحسنت. لقد ضغطت على حرفي : Ctrl+V");
        });
       shortcut.add("Ctrl+X", function() {
    $('span').html("أحسنت. لقد ضغطت على حرفي : Ctrl+X");
        });


});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin for Jquery called "Hotkeys" which allows you to bind to key down combinations.

Does this do what you are after?

[Jquery HotKeys - Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/js-hotkeys/)

Comment: a plugin is kind of overkill for the simplicity of what I need, especially at 4.4kb, it's just too much, thank you though.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var ctrlMode = false; // if true the ctrl key is down
    ///this works
    $(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.ctrlKey){
        ctrlMode = true;
    };
    });
    $(document).keyup(function(e){
    ctrlMode = false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Would you consider adding some narrative to explain why this code works, and what makes it an answer to the question?

Comment: From my testing just now - it seems like IE8 doesn't pass keypressed for *some* special keys (Ctrl-C - no, Ctrl X and V - yes).   Whereas keydown *is* passed, so this answer works.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to do it in jQuery  :

```
/* The elements we'll bind the shortcut keys to. */
var elements = "body, input, select, checkbox, textarea";

/* Bind the key short-cut 'Ctrl+S' to the save function. */
$(elements).bind ("keydown", "ctrl+space", function (e) {
    // Prevent the default operation.
    e.preventDefault ();
    // Stop processing if we're already doing something.
    console.log ("That's right , you pressed correct shortcut!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was looking for a keydown ctrl key and click event.
My jquery looks like this:

```
$('.linkAccess').click( function (event) {
  if(true === event.ctrlKey) {

    /* Extract the value */
    var $link = $('.linkAccess');
    var value = $link.val();

    /* Verified if the link is not null */
    if('' !== value){
      window.open(value);
    }
  }
});
```

Where "linkAccess" is the class name for some specific fields where I have a link and I want to access it using my combination of key and click.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
$(window).keypress("c", function(e) {
  if (!e.ctrlKey)
    return;

  console.info("CTRL +  C detected !");
});
```

```js
$(window).keypress("c", function(e) {
  if (!e.ctrlKey)
    return;

  $("div").show();
});
```

```css
/*https://gist.github.com/jeromyanglim/3952143 */

kbd {
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #000;
  background: #eee;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ccc #aaa #888 #bbb;
  padding: 2px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 0 1px #ffffff inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 0 1px #ffffff inset;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 0 1px #ffffff inset;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  border-color: #CCCCCC #CCCCCC #FFFFFF;
  border-style: solid solid none;
  border-width: 1px 1px medium;
  color: #444444;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display:none">
  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> detected !
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 2019, this works (in Chrome at least)

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    var key = (event.which || event.keyCode) ;
  if(e.ctrlKey) {
        if (key == 26) { console.log('Ctrl+Z was pressed') ; }
        else if (key == 25) { console.log('Ctrl+Y was pressed') ; }
        else if (key == 19) { console.log('Ctrl+S was pressed') ; }
    else { console.log('Ctrl', key, 'was pressed') ; }
    }
});
```