# Way to trigger multiple keypress and hold events in jQuery

Tags: jquery, keyboard

Looking for a way to simulate a multiple keypress using jQuery. For example ALT+F1 (holding down alt and hitting F1).

I've managed to simulate the F1 keypress thanks to:
[Definitive way to trigger keypress events with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832059/definitive-way-to-trigger-keypress-events-with-jquery)

Looking for something like this:

```
$(".f1").click(function() {   
    var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
    e.keyCode = 18; // ALT key pressed
    // while ALT key is pressed, hit the F1 Key
    $("input").trigger(e, function(){
        var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
        e.which = 112; // F1 key
        $("input").trigger(e);
        });
});
```

Comment: Take a look at this post. Hope it helps.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604057/jquery-keypress-ctrlc-or-some-combo-like-that

Answer (score 22, accepted):

With the modifier keys `alt`, `ctrl`, and `shift`, you can use event modifiers specifically for them:

```
$(".f1").click(function() {
    var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
    e.which = 112;       // # F1 code value
    e.altKey = true;     // Alt key pressed
    $("input").trigger(e);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/2kcrg/

Comment: fast and trikly

Answer (score 2):

1. you can't outright simulate keypress events, you can only trigger javascript handlers bound to them.  So consider simply writing a function that encapsulates what you want your keypress to do, having the keypress handler call that function, and "simulate" the keypress in other places by simply calling that same function.
2. if you really must simulate ALT-F1 and similar, you need to set other properties in the `keypress` event (e.g. `altKey` or `metaKey`), and/or first trigger `keydown` event for the press of the modifier key (in JQuery/firefox, pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd> gives me a `keydown` event with `e.which == 18`.).  At the end of the day you just need to create the same events that your  handlers respond to.