# trigger multiple keypress to stimulate keyboard shortcut jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

I want to create page zoom - according to keyboard shortcuts by jQuery. Mainly, I want to trigger `Ctrl` with `+` and `Ctrl` with `-` key pairs, when the user clicks on some element on the page. I have tried this code snippet from [Way to trigger multiple keypress and hold events in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080644/way-to-trigger-multiple-keypress-and-hold-events-in-jquery) question, but it does not work - it does not zoom the page

```
$("#zoom").click(function() {

    var e = $.Event("keydown");
    e.which = 61; // # key code for +
    e.ctrlKey = true;
    $(document).trigger(e);

});
```

Comment: @Kelvin Mackay It does seem to work fine, but it doesn't actually zoom in, like clicking ctrl + = does. at least in chrome

Answer (score 3):

Your event trigger seems to work just fine, according to my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aJdeQ/).

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var d = new Date();
    $('#log').html(
        'time: ' + d.getTime() + '<br/>' +
        'key: ' + e.which + '<br/>' +
        'ctrl: ' + (e.ctrlKey ? 'Yes' : 'No')
    );
});
```

However, you seem to be asking how to control the browser's zoom level, which isn't possible in most (if any) browsers without a plugin.

You *could* implement zooming of your own using CSS and Javascript, and even use the above snippet to capture `Ctrl +` and `Ctrl -` but you wouldn't be able to prevent the user zooming the page in other ways.

CSS:

```
    .text-zoom-0{
        font-size: .75em;
    }
    .text-zoom-1{
        font-size: 1em;
    }
    .text-zoom-2{
        font-size: 1.25em;
    }
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var currentZoom = 1,
        minZoom = 0,
        maxZoom = 2,
        changeZoom = function(increase) {
            var newZoom = currentZoom;

            if (increase && currentZoom < maxZoom) {
                newZoom++;
                $('.text-zoom-' + currentZoom)
                    .addClass('.text-zoom-' + newZoom)
                    .removeClass('.text-zoom-' + currentZoom);
            } else if (currentZoom > minZoom) {
                newZoom--;
                $('.text-zoom-' + currentZoom)
                    .addClass('.text-zoom-' + newZoom)
                    .removeClass('.text-zoom-' + currentZoom);
            }

            currentZoom = newZoom;
        };

    $('.zoomIn').click(function(e) {
        changeZoom(true);
    });

    $('.zoomOut').click(function(e) {
        changeZoom(false);
    });
});
```

And of course you'd have to do the same for images, navigation, and every other element on the page. If you wanted to actually do this, you could be much more clever about the CSS than this little snippet, but remember, *could* is not the same as *should* by any stretch of the imagination...

Comment: This. Can you imagine the chaos if a random, untrusted website could mess with your display settings?

Comment: yes it works, I mean there are no errors or smth, but it does not zoom the page what I want to achieve

Comment: @Davo As I said, controlling the browser's native zoom isn't possible. You could implement your own zoom functionality if you desire using CSS and Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this librarie. there are a lot of examples

http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/

Comment: He's trying to do the opposite of that.