# Jquery keypress trigger

Tags: jquery, eventtrigger

How to trigger key-press of ctrl+ shift+m in jQuery?

I tried the below code for single key.Its working.But i want to trigger all the three keys at the same time.

```js
$(document).on('keypress', function(e) {
  alert(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode));
});

$(document).trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', { which: 77 }));
$(document).trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', {
  which: 77, 
  keyCode: 77 
}));
```

Comment: Simple answer: *don't*. Place the logic in a function and call it from the normal keypress handler, and any location you're trying to run your `trigger()` call. Triggering key-based events is inconsistent at best

Answer (score 0):

you can control it with the code above

```
if ( e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && ( e.which === 77 ) ) {
    console.log( "You pressed CTRL + Shift + m" );
}
```

Hope it helps!! :)

Comment: Thanks. But this is helpful when we need to identify if we have clicked all three keys. But we need to trigger the click of those 3 keys at the same time.

Comment: Oh, okay, you want to trigger the 3 keys at same time from code... okay, I'm sorry. I'll try to find a solution.

Comment: I've found this link, maybe it helps to you: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442457/trigger-multiple-keypress-to-stimulate-keyboard-shortcut-jquery"