# Append div to selected text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show some buttons if someone select text in a editable area  - like this:

[image]

So, I think I have to use `<div contenteditable="true">` instead of `<textarea>`

But to be honest I have no idea how to append the div

Questions:

1. Whats the (jquery) event for selecting text?
2. How to append a div after select to this area?

JsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hA7Zn/

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Where is your try and code?

Comment: @idonteven in the fiddle, at least we have HTML code there.

Comment: I think that comment is ironic...it´s just a div...there is no try or js...

Comment: i have no idea how to start, so no code so far :/ need some hints for the questions above

Comment: You have a function to get selected text here ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081277/detect-what-is-copied-from-webpage-with-jquery/24083504#24083504

Comment: @JoffreyMaheo thanks, but i dont want to get the selected text only if someone copied it, isnt there any event that fires just after a selection?

Comment: @Aaroniker : Try Google Dictionary chrome extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-dictionary-by-goog/mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja?hl=en), it exactly works the way you want your to work. Hope it helps.

Comment: @ParagGangil thanks, but i want to write a jquery script for that, so that everyone can use this without the chrome extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hA7Zn/1/)** for getting selected text,

Event **[selectstart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536969%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** is fired in case of selection

```
$(function () {
    $('div').on('selectstart', function () {
        console.log('..');
        $(document).one('mouseup', function() {
            alert(this.getSelection());
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: this is what i searched for (but does not work in firefox) - next i can wrap the selected text with a div and prepend my buttons?

Comment: I'm working on it. Succesfull with appending div, but cannot append button.

Comment: found this for cross browser support: http://mark.koli.ch/use-javascript-and-jquery-to-get-user-selected-text

Comment: That's a great addition to my knowledge. I needed a cross browser solution too

Answer (score 1):

Selecting the text:

```
var text = $('text_element').text();
```

Selecting the html:

```
var html = $('text_element').html()
```

Appending data:

```
$('appending_element').append(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to append the div in the end of your div, use [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

OR

If you want to add your div after some particular div, use [.insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/).

Answer (score 0):

May be this code will help you:-

```
<textarea cols="45" rows="5" id="message">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</textarea>
<script>

$("textarea").click(function(){
    var txt=document.getElementById("message");
    alert(txt.value.substr(txt.selectionStart, (txt.selectionEnd -txt.selectionStart)));
});
</script>
```