# text is not copying to the clipboard

Tags: javascript, html, zeroclipboard

1. When page is refreshed, it generate the prompt message that text is copyed, but when trying to paste it via ctrl+v it returns nothing

   ```
   <html>
   <head>
   <script>
   var clip = new ZeroClipboard(document.getElementById('my-button'));
   </script><br>
   </head>
   <body>
   <button id="my-button" data-clipboard-text="Copy me!">Copy to clip</button>
   <script>
   alert("copyed");
   </script>
   </body>
   ```

Comment: Do you want something like this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081277/detect-what-is-copied-from-webpage-with-jquery/24083504#24083504

Comment: This might be a stupid question but did you include the ZeroClipboard? <script src="ZeroClipboard.js"></script>

Comment: Take a look at the "simple example" https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard