# A simple e.altKey test

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard, key, keypress

**Summary:**

I want to catch the event of `Alt + Z` `onkeypress`. I am using `e.altKey` to accomplish this.
However, it isn't working anywhere, from `textarea`s to `input`s to `div[contenteditable]`s!

---

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/M693m/4/)**

The event of `Shift + any_key` (`any_key !== Alt`) works fine, but `Alt` isn't detected at all. I tested with `keydown`, which works perfectly.

---

I don't know if it is related, but the `ctrl` key also doesn't work in my fiddle. I have seen `ctrl` key being caught `onkeypress` in various answers like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4604093/2675672 , but I have zero idea why it doesn't work in my fiddle.

By *not working*, I mean that, even no `alert` boxes pop up.

It must be something simple which I might be overlooking.

---

**Note:** Only Chrome support required, without any libraries. Also, my <kbd>Alt</kbd> key isn't broken. I can press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and open the File menu in Chrome just fine.

**EDIT:**

So, it is realized that this is a [Chrome bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2606) that the event doesn't fire (noticed by [@Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy)). Still, if anyone has any workarounds for making this work. Please share them. Thanks!

---

**UPDATE:** it's been 3 years. Is it ok for Chromium bugs to take years to fix? Or should I just forget it (I'd forgotten this question already, just came across it while maintenance work)

Comment: It works fine if you assign the event handler properly http://jsfiddle.net/CPsRe/ *edit* wait no that's wrong; it works no matter what in Firefox. It's Chrome that's the problem here. See this for example: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2606

Comment: @Pointy Thanks for the reply, but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Yes I realized that I was mistaken. Chrome just has bad behavior with keyboard events (and probably Safari too; it seems to be a WebKit issue).

Answer (score 1):

Onkeypress doesn't fire for all keys.

You need to use onkeydown.

> Note: The onkeypress event is not fired for all keys (e.g. ALT, CTRL,
>   SHIFT, ESC) in all browsers. To detect only whether the user has
>   pressed a key, use the onkeydown event instead, because it works for
>   all keys.

Quote from: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp

Comment: What if I press `Alt + Z`? That way, `Z` is being pressed and so the event should fire I believe. Also, then why does `Shift` key work when it's written it should not? ("all keys (e.g. ALT, CTRL, SHIFT, ESC) "?

Comment: Stop using keypress at all. Do everything with keydown. Those were just examples, but i have no idea why that works. Probably in IE or other browsers it is not working.