# Trigger focus = false with jquery.hotkeys on input[type=text]

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://liveweave.com/tq7rwk

Is there anyway to dynamically unfocus (focus = false) a textbox or textarea element?

I tried triggering [.blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) and [.focusut](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/) but those only apply when it is focused out. It won't trigger a focus out event.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+1', function() {
  alert("hotkey triggered");
  if ( $(".txtbox").is(":focus") ) {
    $(".txtbox").trigger('focusout');
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you want to take out the focus?

Comment: Yes I want to take out the focus.

Comment: user:747579 did this with jquery plugin, have a look at :[stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15495327/2922310)

Comment: Looks like I'm gonna have to change libraries. This works fine compared to the other one. - http://liveweave.com/J8Xdc6 Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use the [shortcut.js](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55765722/delivred/abdennour/lib/js/shortcut_.js) Javascript library by [Binny V A](http://www.binnyva.com/).

What's great about this library is you can use a key combination like **CTRL+T** (which in most web browsers is a native hotkey to make a new tab. This script will allow you to use your custom hotkey function and will not call the browser's custom hotkey.

```
shortcut.add("Ctrl+N", function() {
  alert("Called new document");
});
```

Here's the new revised fiddle: http://liveweave.com/GWjbUc

Answer (score 0):

just use:

```
$('.txtbox').blur();
```

to set the focus use: `.focus()`

or detect the keyCode:

```
$('input').on('keydown', function(e) {
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 81) { // if Ctrl+Q (dont use Ctrl+1, in chrome its jump to tab 1)
        $(this).blur();
    }
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/99SP4/2/**

Comment: I already tried this as stated in my original post, and it does not seem to work with the jquery.hotkeys library I'm using.

Comment: @mikethedj4, see my update. list of keyCodes here:
http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes