# Wierd issue with key press combination

Tags: javascript, jquery, combinations, keypress

im using this code which i found here, on a stackoverflow post for keypress combination:

```
$(document).keypress("c",function(e) {
    if(e.ctrlKey) {
        alert('Combined');
    }
});
```

The thing is, i'm not sure what is the meaning of the "c", but this code will alert only on Ctrl+z, and i've tried to replace that "c", but still it only works on Ctrl+z.

This is where i found that code:
[jquery: keypress, ctrl+c (or some combo like that)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604057/jquery-keypress-ctrlc-or-some-combo-like-that)

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*this code will alert only on Ctrl+z, and i've tried to replace that "c", but still it only works on Ctrl+z*

That's not true. This code works on any combination Ctrl+[key].

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6891vkL4/)

So your issue **cannot be reproduced**.

Regarding to `"c"` as the first argument of `.keypress` method: According to [manual](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) the first argument (`"c"` in your case), if present, is passed to the event handler as property `data` of `Event` object.
So you can access it by `e.data` notation in your event handler (see Demo).

Comment: Ok well i have tried many buttons, and so far only ctrl+z and Ctrl+q worked but i guess its because other combinations are browser shortcuts (even though some combinations didnt do anything). thanks

Answer (score 1):

there "c" doesn't do anything you can remove it.
it alerts only on CTRL+Z because in if condition is e.ctrlKey if you remove it and write like this

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    alert('Combined')
});
```

it alerts on every keypress

Comment: The purpose of this code is to alert on Ctrl+c press. this is where i found this code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604057/jquery-keypress-ctrlc-or-some-combo-like-that