# How to capture ALT+C keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want catch an event for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> or something like that. My code is
html

```
<input type="text" id="name"/>
```

JavaScript

```
$("#name").keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 67 && e.keyCode == 18){alert(e.keyCode);} 
});
```

where is the problem? How it works on both Chrome & firefox?

Comment: I think you need to look into the `e.altKey` and `e.ctrlKey`.  Try the answers in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93695/best-cross-browser-method-to-capture-ctrls-with-jquery or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604057/jquery-keypress-ctrlc-or-some-combo-like-that

Comment: I understand your confusion, but if you think about it, `e.keyCode` can't be two different values at the same time. So if you need to check for two keypresses at once, you'll need a different mechanism. That's what `e.altKey` is for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check for [`e.altKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent.altKey) instead:

```
if(e.altKey && e.keyCode == 67){alert(e.keyCode);}
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you are checking for two codes as the same time.  The event (`e`) has several values you can work with ... including `altKey` which is a boolean (true or false) ...

Try ... watching the `e.altKey` and the `e.keyCode` values.

```
$("#name").keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.altKey && e.keyCode == 67) {
        alert(e.keyCode);
    } 
});
```

With the right version of jQuery, there should be no issue between browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
//console.log(e.keyCode); If you want to check other keys code
if(e.keyCode == 67 || e.keyCode == 18){
console.log("alt or c pressed");
}
});
```

You can work around this to check if the two keys are pressed at the same time. I sujest you to use an aux var set to zero wich increase his value when keydown event triggered and decrease it when keyup.