# Using jQuery, why is this function being called when I only click one of the two keys?

Tags: jquery, keydown

I have this code:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+1', function () {
    alert('You found the hotkey ctrl+1!');
});
```

But if I click on *either* the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or the <kbd>1</kbd> key, this code seems to fire.  I only want this code to fire when *both* keys are pressed.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using some sort of plugin for that? Bind is `.bind( eventType [, eventData ], handler )` there is no filter for what keys are pressed.

Comment: What about other remaining keys in your keyboard? Are they not triggering your alert() ?

Comment: @epascarello That looks like they are using (or think they are using) the jQuery Hotkeys plug-in https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys/blob/master/README.md

Comment: A bounty added a year later?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/keydown/), the second argument to the `bind` function is `eventData`, which is

> An object containing data that will be passed to the event handler.

This is used to access variables from outside the inner function which you use as a handler, to avoid the problem with accessing a mutable variables from closure.

If you want to filter the keys that trigger the action just handle it inside of the function.

```
$(document).bind("keydown", function(ev){ // notice the function argument
    if(ev.ctrlKey && ev.keyCode == 49){ // 49 being the keyCode for "1"
        alert("Foo!");
    }
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't this also handle Ctrl+Alt+1, as well as Ctrl+Shift+1?

Comment: @RolandIllig yes, it would get triggered as it checks only if Ctrl&&1 is pressed. As long as the key combination doesn't get *picked up* by a higher layer which would prevent it getting to your code it would get triggered. For example if we would be expecting Ctrl+L and you'd press Ctrl+Alt+L the combination would be handled by Windows first as a locking action and wouldn't be passed on to the browser if I'm not mistaken. I'm sure you get my point here. Same may happen on JS level where one action simply prevents the event being handled by another handler - ev.stopPropagation()

Answer (score 3):

You can use the keydown function of jQuery directly and check for the keys pressed.

```
$('body').keydown(function (e){
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 49)
        alert("Ctrl+1 pressed");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
document.body.addEventListener('keypress', function (event) {
    var key = event.which || event.keyCode;
    if(key.ctrlKey && key == 49) {
        alert("Ctrl+1 pressed);
    }
}
```

This should help. You add an event *listener* to the *body* of your HTML code and listen for which key was pressed.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    document.body.addEventListener('keypress', function (event) {
        var key = event.which || event.keyCode;
        if (key.ctrlKey || key == 49) {
            alert("Ctrl+1 pressed");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>empty page</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it valid HTML to have the `script` tag outside the `html` tag?

Answer (score 3):

The keyword "+" becomes of a CSS selector. It is not a listener to keyboard events (keydown, keypress, and keyup).

In this context, you don’t need a CSS selector to detect key. This magic correspond to an event, and for this reason there is a function that receives the event ...**function (event)** or **function(e)**. That parameter contains everything that you need.

Now the event identifies the key by property **"which"** or property **"keyCode"**. Here is a sort of complex, because which and keycode, depends on the browser support.

For now, maybe must check the keydown event on the jQuery page, observe the line 41, and the result when you press a key, specially the keycode and the which attributes.

Finally, the target is detecting the Ctrl key simultaneously with another key. It is important to know it is a special key, and which number must be replaced by **ctrlKey** and evaluate the number by the property which or keyCode.

jQuery link to keydown and example that make you know what key number (which or keycode) are you press is [here](https://api.jquery.com/keydown/).

Your code finally will look like this:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function (e) {
    if((e.crtlKey && (e.which == 49)) || (e.crtlKey && (e.which == 97))) {
        alert('You found the hotkey ctrl+1!');
    }
});
```

The number 49 in the code corresponding to the number ="1" in the alphabetical keyboard part.

The number 97 corresponds to the number ="1" in the numerical keyboard part.

Comment: Is the name of the attribute *"which"* or *"wich"* (four instances)?

Answer (score 2):

Directly use the jQuery event instead of bind. Use the `ctrlKey` property of the event object to know if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> was pressed.

```
$(document).keydown("1", function(e){
    if(e.ctrlKey)
        alert("Ctrl+1 pressed");
});
```

It wasn't tested, but I guess it should work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check for a **keydown** event as well as if the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key was pressed

```
$(document).keydown('1', function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        alert('Ctrl 1 was pressed.');
    }
});
```

Just to clarify on your question, you missed checking the *ctrl* event.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of [jQuery hotKeys](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys). It will make your life much easier. You will be able to do something like:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+1', function () {
    alert('You found the hotkey ctrl+1!');
});
```

Another library is [Mouse trap](https://craig.is/killing/mice). It lets you do things like:

```
Mousetrap.bind('command+shift+k', function(e) {
    highlight([6, 7, 8, 9]);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. The key down event fires at the moment when you press a key and it does not care if you are pressing another key. Please use the keyup event.

```js
$(document).bind('keyup', 'ctrl+1', function () {
    alert('You found the hotkey ctrl+1!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(document).keypress("1",function(e) {
  if(e.ctrlKey)
    alert("You found the hotkey ctrl+1!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Press CTRL+1 to show alert.</p>
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4604093/5364144).

Answer (score -2):

This function will be called on each key press, but I have checked for keycodes in a condition. We can implement the required functionality in the "if condition". The condition will execute only when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and <kbd>1</kbd> is pressed.

```
$(document).on('keydown', 'body', function(event) {

    if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 49) {

        alert("Ctrl+1 pressed");
    }
});
```

Comment: No Explanation?