# call function when document ready and onkeypress

Tags: jquery

I'm have no basic on jQuery, so really need help with this one.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        alert('Warning!!');
        document.write('prohibited);});
```

the code above is not made by me, but from my understanding is when the document is ready or finish load up it will call the function, and display window message and write on the document.

what i want to ask is how to combine it with keypress, let say when someone try to view source, so when the document is ready, and someone press ctrl+u then it will call the `function`, then display the `alert`, and do the `document.write`

Thank you :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery: keypress, ctrl+c (or some combo like that)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604057/jquery-keypress-ctrlc-or-some-combo-like-that)

Comment: i'm sorry if this a duplicate, because maybe i search with a wrong keyword before when i try to find answer to this problem, but thanks btw, i will try to read the discussion

Answer (score 0):

You can write key press event this way:

```
$(document).on("KeyPress",function(event){
if(event.which == 55 && cntrlIsPressed)
{
alert('Do Something');
document.write('prohibited');
}        
});
```

Comment: i try it but it doesn't call the function, alert and document.write at all

Comment: still doesn't work, crtl+u function like normal. for the `function()` i write in ext file, so what i intend the script to do is when the document is ready, it will run the `function()` and popup `alert` and do the `document.write` if ctrl+u is pressed,