# Can jQuery detect when user pressed Ctrl+F key at the same time?

Tags: jquery

I want to make an alert when the user do Ctrl+F on the page. But I tried to do keydown just like below.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 17 && e.keyCode == 70) {
        alert('Hello World!');
    }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery: keypress, ctrl+c (or some combo like that)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604057/jquery-keypress-ctrlc-or-some-combo-like-that)

Comment: `e.keyCode` could not possibly have two values, could it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ctrlKey` function of javascript with key 'F'

```
$(document).keypress("f",function(event) {
  if(event.ctrlKey)
    alert("Find key.");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 70 && e.ctrlKey) {
            alert('ctrl F');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank! this woks!

Answer (score 0):

just use `.ctrlKey` property of the event object that gets passed in. It indicates if `Ctrl` was pressed at the time of the event.

```
$(document).on("keypress","f",function(e) {
  if(e.ctrlKey)
    alert("Ctrl+F");
});
```