# Add or modify text/ content in contenteditable div without execCommand?

Tags: javascript

The document.execCommand() has been obsoleted [[DOC]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand). So, Making WYSIWYG  editor is not that easy in 2020. After reading a lot of articles and answers I just find, Most of the answers (developers) prefer to use :

- document.createRange()
- window.getSelection()
- appendChild
- insertBefore
- nextSibling.
- replaceChild, etc

But how? They didn't give any example. I want to make the "Voldemort" word bold after clicking on the `B` button. I just need an idea of the workflow.

```html
<div class="block-editor">
  <!-- editor control -->
  <div class="block-editor-control">
    <ul>
      <li data-action="bold"> B </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- editor content's -->
  <div class="block-editor-content">
    <div class="block-editor-block" contenteditable="true" role="group">
       Voldemort is back
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This article: https://medium.com/@jitubutwal144/three-different-ways-to-build-inline-content-editor-using-javascrpit-d58c2edac9cb appears to have the example that you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

First, detect Ctrl+B key press ([keypress, ctrl+c (or some combo like that)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604057/keypress-ctrlc-or-some-combo-like-that#answer-4604093)). After that:

1. Get the selection range: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection.
2. Insert `<span>` at beginning of the range, and insert `</span>`  at the end of the range
3. Set the span element's font weight to bold.

Comment: How to insert the span on the specific char position

Comment: Hey, I just realized that Ctrl+B, Ctrl+U, and Ctrl+I shortcuts all work in Chrome and Microsoft Edge. What browser are you using such that you are facing this issue? I will need to download it to troubleshoot.

Comment: You don't need to worry about the keyboard shortcut. I said when someone clicks on a specific button like here I have a button named B(keyboard shortcut not necessary). I just need the main concept of how to insert the span on the specific char position

Comment: So first you get the beginning and the end of the range. Next, you insert the string `"</span>"` at the end. After that, you insert the string `"<span>"` at the beginning. All of this can be done with javascript's slice function - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice.