# jQuery on("input paste") triggers twice after pasting

Tags: jquery, paste

I want to check whether the URL has been input into textarea or not. This is a function that checks textarea:

```
$('#text textarea').on('input paste', function() {
            checkUrl($(this));
        });
```

Only one URL is allowed, so after finding the URL handler is unbind using off:

```
function checkUrl(elem) {

var words = elem.val().split(/\s+/);
$.each(words, function(index, element) {
    if (isValidURL($.trim(element))) {          
        $.ajax({...}); // Ajax call
        elem.off('input paste');
        return;
    }
});
```

}

Function checkUrl is called not only once but twice after pasting the URL (CTRT+V). Ajax is also triggered twice.

Thanks a lot in advance.

**EDIT**

I've changed my code according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902455/how-do-i-capture-the-input-value-on-a-paste-event):

```
$('#text textarea').bind('paste', function() {
        var _this = $(this);
        setTimeout( function() {
            checkUrl(_this);
        }, 100);
    });
```

It's now working with paste handler only, but the main problem persists...

Comment: `input` includes all methods of input, including pasting. Is there a reason for explicitly adding `paste`?

Comment: No, I've just seen "input paste" here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686995/jquery-catch-paste-input

Comment: I've tried input only, but it's the same

Comment: "CTRL" and "V" might cause the problem...

Comment: Please paste your HTML code, or create a JSFiddle replicating your problem. It'll help us to help you.

Comment: Well, it's not that easy :) I've found out that this "doble trigger" error happens only first time, when the page is loaded

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue on Chrome, nor when the page is first loaded. See http://jsfiddle.net/8SgYH/. What browser/OS are you using?

Comment: Win7 32b, FF latest. I think there are two same handlers for pasting...but I can't find them...

Comment: I cannot reproduce in Firefox 16. If I only bind `input`, then it's always triggered once, as expected. Does the fiddle show the issue for you? If not, there must be something else happening in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have solved the problem. Before binding events I´ve unbound everything from the element.

```
$('#text textarea').unbind();   
$('#text textarea').bind('paste', function() {
        var _this = $(this);
        setTimeout( function() {
            checkUrl(_this);
    }, 100);
})
```

Comment: Note that `bind`/`unbind` are deprecated. You'd better continue using `on`/`off`.

Comment: doesn't help me, now it fires even more times: paste, input, input

Answer (score 1):

Get the event object and check for the event type 'input' so if its a paste event it will trigger the input event

you can try this

```
$('#text textarea').on('input paste',function(event){


    if(event.type=='input'){
       checkUrl($(this));
    }
 });​
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nLPrG/

Comment: I really like this solution.  Very Elegant!