# jQuery - on text change while user typing or paste

Tags: jquery, text, keyup

I'm new to jQuery and I've tried to make something but I failed so here is my problem
when the user type it works but when the user paste something didn't work !!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('#username').keyup(username_check);
});
```

the username_check function :

```
function username_check(){  
var username = $('#username').val();
if(username == "" || username.length < 4){
alert("error");
}
```

the field :

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I capture the input value on a paste event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902455/how-do-i-capture-the-input-value-on-a-paste-event)

Answer (score 40):

If you want to capture all `input` events:

```
$('#username').on("input", username_check);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. I want to turn a button on when someone types anything into a box. removed on change listener and added this.

Comment: IE9 though doesn't fully support that event (https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-event).

Answer (score 25):

Use `.on()` or `.bind()` to bind multiple events,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#username').on('keyup paste',username_check);
});


function username_check(){ 
    setTimeout( function() {
        var username = $('#username').val();
    },100);
    if(username == "" || username.length < 4){
      alert("error");
    }
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jU762/2/)**