# JavaScript keyboard shortcuts with modifier keys?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have keyboard shortcut that executes some jQuery:

```
$('body').on('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 70) {
    $('html').addClass('example');
    $('#example').focus();
    return false;
  }
});
```

When the user presses `f`, it'll execute the jQuery.

How can I change the `keyCode` so instead of it being `f`, I'd like it to be when the user presses `alt + f`?

This is what I tried:

```
$('body').on('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 18 && 70) {
    $('html').addClass('example');
    $('#example').focus();
    return false;
  }
});
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i detect keyboard modifier(ctrl or Shift) through javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539493/how-can-i-detect-keyboard-modifierctrl-or-shift-through-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Keyboard events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/KeyboardEvent) have attributes for the modifier keys:

```
if (e.keyCode == 18 && e.altKey) {

}
```

Comment: Ah, I had no idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`$('#example')` selects the *ID* `example`. Use `$('.example')` instead. Also you should use `e.keyCode == 70 && e.altKey`.

Comment: `#example` was just an example although I am using an idea because the element is specific.