# Trigger event on hold of shift+enter key

Tags: javascript

I was trying to call a function on the press of the **shift + enter** key.

What I was trying is this

```js
$('.o_searchview_input').on('keydown', function(event) {
debugger;
  if (event.keyCode == 13 && !event.shiftKey) {
    $(this).trigger(jQuery.Event("keydown", {
      keyCode: 13, // ENTER
      shiftKey: true
    }));
  } else if (event.keyCode == 13 && event.shiftKey) {
    console.log('shift + enter');
  }
});
```

But it is pressing the **shift** key automatically.

I am worried is there any option in JavaScript to trigger an even on the press of two keys?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect keyboard modifier (Ctrl or Shift) through JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539493/how-to-detect-keyboard-modifier-ctrl-or-shift-through-javascript) also see: [KeyboardEvent.getModifierState()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539493/how-to-detect-keyboard-modifier-ctrl-or-shift-through-javascript)

Comment: You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014702/how-do-i-detect-shiftenter-and-generate-a-new-line-in-textarea

Answer (score 2):

There is no event that checks if multiple keys are pressed.
If you want to check for 2 keys you will need to create `keydown` and `keyup` events to track which keys are pressed but not released manually.

The exception to this rule is `Shift` `Alt` and `Ctrl`/`Cmd`
These are known as key modifiers and can be used like in your example:

`if (event.keyCode == 13 && event.shiftKey) // do something`

Answer (score 0):

Using `event.preventDefault()` on `shift + enter` does the job for you

```js
$('.o_searchview_input').on('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13 && event.shiftKey) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent default action
    console.log('shift + enter');
    // call your function
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

`Enter` adds new line, Where as `Shift + Enter` is prevented
<textarea class="o_searchview_input"></textarea>
```