# How to disable Ctrl C/V using javascript for both internet explorer and firefox browsers

Tags: javascript

I am making this javascript code in order to disable Ctlr+c and Ctlr+v, prenscreen, ALT+TAB, Ctlr+S, and PrintScreen keys.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">

function Disable_Control_C() {
var keystroke = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();

if (event.ctrlKey && (keystroke == 'c' || keystroke == 'v')) {
alert("let's see");
event.returnValue = false; // disable Ctrl+C
}
}

</script>
</head>
<body onkeydown="javascript:Disable_Control_C()">
Hello World!
</body>
</html>
```

unfortunately, code is working on IE browser, but not working on firefox. Can anyone here advice?

Comment: If your goal is to prevent users from "stealing" your content, that is really impossible (just use Fiddler, and you've captured everything anyway).  As a user, I would find all this keyboard control largely annoying.

Comment: Maybe you can tell what the general purpose you are trying to achieve. Are you planning on disabling the corresponding items in popup menus?

Comment: This code will be added to testing web application that will have a new functionality as CBT Test. Other points like maximizing and minimizing and such things will be handled in a different way. My main target here is to disable keyboard keys I've mentioned in my question.

Comment: Please select an answer if the issue has been resolved

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect ctrl+v ,Ctrl+c using Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903991/how-to-detect-ctrlv-ctrlc-using-javascript)

Answer (score 28):

- I don't like when browsers do this to me, and
- It's easy to work around, and
- This doesn't count as "secure" by any definition, but

---

Use `element.on(?:`[`copy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.oncopy)|[`cut`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.oncut)|[`paste`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onpaste)`)`

```
<body oncopy="return false" oncut="return false" onpaste="return false">
```

Answer (score 15):

you can use it jquery for this. You just need to bind the `cut`, `copy` and `paste` function with your element.

And add this Jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Selector').bind('copy paste', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: I need to use javascript only and not jQuery.

Comment: Ha ha, you will rarely find a Javascript question where nobody gives a jQuery solution!

Comment: Thank you for actually providing an answer. Some notes about why one shouldn't do this are fine, but _sometimes_ it's useful to do this anyway (e.g. if it's just for casual users, if preventing copy/pasting is not _critical_, etc.). So thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am working on React project. We also have the same requirement to prevent copy/paste/right click.

Use the below code in index.html `<body/>` tag. This will prevent all unnecessary actions.

```
<body oncopy="return false;" oncut="return false;" onpaste="return false;" oncontextmenu="return false;">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Disable Right click
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());

// Disable key down
document.onkeydown = disableSelectCopy;

// Disable mouse down
document.onmousedown = dMDown;

// Disable click
document.onclick = dOClick;

function dMDown(e) { return false; }

function dOClick() { return true; }

function disableSelectCopy(e) {
    // current pressed key
    var pressedKey = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).toLowerCase();
    if ((e.ctrlKey && (pressedKey == "c" || pressedKey == "x" || pressedKey == "v" || pressedKey == "a" || pressedKey == "u")) ||  e.keyCode == 123) {
        return false;
    }
}
```