# Disabling document.execCommand("copy") to false

Tags: javascript, angular

How can I make my selected string to null. So that I am not able to paste.
I tried with `document.execCommand('copy') = false;` 
But it didn't work. Can I get any solution?.

Comment: Unable to understand!

Comment: how to make document.execCommand('copy') returns false?

Comment: If you run this `console.log(document.execCommand('copy'));` is showing `false`!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21743267/6027891

Answer (score 0):

You can always rewrite execCommand to ignore copy

```
document._execCommand = document.execCommand;
document.execCommand = function () {  
  if (arguments[0] !== 'copy') return document._execCommand.apply(this, arguments);
  return false;
}
```