# How to turn off right click and ctrl+c behaviour in ASP .NET MVC WebApplication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, web-applications, copy-paste

I write a web application in ASP .NET MVC which will be used only by authorized users. I will configure machines(PCs, tablets) they will use. I need to protect personal data in webapplication from stealing it. I am obligated by law to prevent those situations.

I already wrote keylogger detecting PrintScreen and sending me info about user to my mail when he uses. I will block unused USB ports, log user actions inside WebApplication and few other things.

But it is not enough I need to void/turn off right mouse button click and ctrl+c combination. It is hard to find information how to do this globally for the site.

**Question:** How to turn off right click and ctrl+c behaviour in ASP .NET MVC WebApplication

Answer (score 0):

Bad news: You can't. If a user uses their smart phone to take a picture of your data, you can't stop that. Also; turning off Right click or Ctrl+C takes Javascript being enabled. If a user turns off JavaScript, they've defeated your 'protection'.

Without knowing more about the industry or the regulations you're specifically charged with, it's hard to say what you can do technically speaking.

If you can guarantee that users can't turn off JavaScript, can't go to the JavaScript console, can't take pictures of the screen with their phones, and can't write down that information on pen and paper, then we can talk.

There's already a Stack Overflow question out there on [how to disable right click in a web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page), as well as [one for disabling 'Ctrl+C'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394957/how-to-disable-ctrl-c-v-using-javascript-for-both-internet-explorer-and-firefox).