# Triggering alert box when user presses ALT+v

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

I would like to be able to trigger an alert box when the user presses ALT+v.

Using a function similar to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("body").keypress(function(event) {
            if (event.which == alt+v) {
            alert('text to display in alert box');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Exact dupilcate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903991/how-to-detect-ctrlv-ctrlc-using-javascript

Comment: Didn't see this in my search before posting.

Comment: no issues.Delete this post :)

Comment: You ca do like [here][1] with alt key code: 18


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903991/how-to-detect-ctrlv-ctrlc-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the answer:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 113) {
        alert("alert text");
    }
});
```