# bind to every keypress but paste

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [jquery copy paste methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14753390/1252748) to do something when text is pasted into my text area

```
$(function(){
    $("#input").bind({
        paste : function(){    
            show_ln();
            $("#t2").scrollTop($("#input").scrollTop());    
        }
    });
});
```

But I want to do something else when any other keypress within `#input` is done.

```
   $("body").on("keypress", "#input", function(){
        show_ln();
    });
```

Is there any way to bind that second keypress to everything *but* a paste?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `keyup` event instead or lookup for the keyCode in `keypress` listener.

```
$("body").on("keyup", "#input", function(event){
    // For the case paste also fires this event you can have a look on keyCode.
    if(event.keyCode!=="NUMBER_OF_PASTE"){
       show_ln();
    }
});
```