# use js function with parameters as a jQuery callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, callback, parameters

I have a js function with a parammeter:

```
function dimension(id){
    val = {
    acMaximize : [
        ["#container", "100%", "90%"]
    ],
    acMinimize : [
        ["#container", "70%", "60%"]
    ],
};
var sub = val[id];
var sub1;
for(i in sub){
    sub1 = sub[i];
    $(sub1[0]).css({
        width : sub1[1],
        height : sub1[2]
    });
}
}
```

And I've tried calling this function in bind method:

```
$(document).bind("keydown", "Ctrl+A", dimension(id)); // <-- this didn't work.
```

How could I do this?

//Edit

Just in case of jQuery Hotkeys.

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Can you post a real world example? What kind of event is `param1` and what's `param2`?. Also `bind` is deprecated.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I've just edited my question. Thanks for your response.

Comment: It is still very unclear what you want to do. Would I be correct in saying you want `CTRL+A` to trigger the function `dimension()`?

Comment: I've just edited again. ~~.

Comment: I've found a previous question about detecting `CTRL+C` and `CTRL+V`, which you could modify to use `CTRL+A` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903991/how-to-detect-ctrlv-ctrlc-using-javascript)

Comment: Actually, it's not my concern. I just want to use a js function as a callback function of bind method.

Comment: Since you can *only* use a JS function as the callback function, I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: The point is, my method didn't work.

Comment: Did you get any errors? (Check the console)

Comment: The function runs when I use that code. It doesn't *do* anything because you are trying to loop over `undefined`, but it runs.

Comment: I don't really get it. It returned error "Uncaught TypeError: Object Ctrl+A has no method 'apply' ".