# jQuery Number Validation only allow keys to Select All, Copy and Paste

Tags: jquery

I tried to find one but I couldn't find any.
I want a jQuery code that will accepts only numbers, of course allow 
"Ctrl+aC, "Ctrl+c", "Ctrl+v", "Ctrl+x", "command+a", "command+c", "command+v", "command+x", "home", "end", "left", "right", "up" and "down"
and doesn't allow extended ASCII specially (´¨ˆ˜) because no matter what was the code when I tested it with the "alt + n" , "e" , "u" or "i" it will show these (´¨ˆ˜).

Comment: have you tried jquery validator !

Comment: this code really prevents extended ascii, but is it possible to use it without submitting I think no, right ? also I want to prevent the user from entering anything else except numbers before submission. whenever keydown check then allow it or not if it's number print it in the textbox else don't

Comment: check my fiddle which has fiddle url  what you expect

Comment: I tried this one the problem is that it allows (´¨ˆ˜) these are alt+some of the keys also It doesn't allow command+a, command+c, command+v and command+x but I have an idea how to fix this problem. the only thing that I couldn't find a solution for it —> these (´¨ˆ˜).

Comment: Please share your code snippet

Comment: I tried these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery , http://jsfiddle.net/yrshaikh/44pc78pj/  , https://snipt.net/GerryEng/jquery-making-textfield-only-accept-numeric-values/ , http://www.tricksofit.com/2014/10/allow-only-numbers-in-textbox-jquery#.VpCK1zZtlsM , and a lot approximately similar but nothing work with these (´¨ˆ˜) they always appear.

Comment: can u please share your code

Comment: the one that I'm working on ? I don't have one yet because nothing work so, I deleted every single code that didn't work and the links that I shared with you are some of them no matter what was the code whenever I press the alt key + n ,e,u or i these will appear(˜´¨ˆ)

Comment: so add that in  your question

Comment: sorry if my question was unclear and thank you for your help.

Comment: you are welcome @Nysa, Accept the answer, if my answer solved your problem else edit your question and let me know your current issue.

Comment: thank you @Venkatraman . here my edited question I wish it will be solved.

Comment: check the title i'm sure its works out for you !

Comment: @Nysa, check whether my answer is what you're looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED** by checking the input value on each `keypress` or `input` event, and if the inserted char is not a number, *even the* `´¨ˆ˜` , we filter it out , but still support keyboard copying and pasting, home end, up, down, left, and right.

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/ok9jadob/)

```js
$('#theField').on('keypress input', function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  value = value.replace(/\D+/, ''); // removes any non-number char
  $(this).val(value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" id="theform">
  <input type="text" id="theField" name="theField">
  <button id="theBtn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: i'm able to enter character but it should not. i meant "e"

Comment: Oh it is other browsers, Chrome doesn't let you

Comment: i checked in chrome latest browser

Comment: Couldn't reproduce in Chrome

Comment: Nice its fixed with latest update. copy and paste the string. it should be restricted

Comment: oh it's just the `e` without `alt`

Comment: No this is not same answer as before, the previous didn't include javascript it was depending on `input type="number"`, however I'm still not sure if this is what the OP is looking for

Comment: @Mi-Creativity thank you so much. finally it's working!! even without the form part if anyone wants to try it without it it's working. I'm really happy right now. thanks a lot guys for helping me .

Comment: @Nysa you welcome, and yes it works on the input itself not the form as whole, I'm glad it helped

Answer (score 3):

Use [`jQuery Validator`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/number-method/)

Check the library for you identify any keys which is written by me.
https://github.com/ramsunvtech/ejs/blob/master/e.js

*How to E.js?*

```
E.key.isHome();
E.key.isAlphabet();
```

Refer this on [How to detect Ctrl+V, Ctrl+C using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903991/how-to-detect-ctrlv-ctrlc-using-javascript)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Makes "field" required and a decimal number only.</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/site-demos.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="myform">
        <label for="field">Required, decimal number: </label>
        <input class="left" id="field" name="field">
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Validate!">
    </form>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // just for the demos, avoids form submit
        jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
            debug: true,
            success: "valid"
        });
        $("#myform").validate({
            rules: {
                field: {
                    required: true,
                    number: true
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Fiddle URL  for key validation:
http://jsfiddle.net/4m5cfe16/