# How to select and copy multiple <td> value on double click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

i want to select multiple  and then copy (ctrl+c).in my code is

```
<table id="tbl1" border="1">
<tr>
    <td>first</td>
    <td>second</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>third</td>
    <td>4th</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>5th</td>
    <td>6th</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

my table will show like

```
______________
|first|second|
_____________
|third|4th   |
_____________
|5th  |6th   |
______________
```

Here if i double click over "second" , "third" and "5th" then this 3 cells should be selected and then i will use ctrl+c to copy and paste this data in wordpad,i tried dblclick but it works only in firefox.

Comment: Hi Joker... What have you done so far?

Comment: simply i want to select and copy "second" , "third" and "5th"

Comment: i have used... function dblclick(e,uri,dec,ip,tariff,serv)
    {   if (parseInt(navigator.appVersion)>3) {   var evt = e ? e:window.event;    var ctrlPres=0;
        var altPres=0;
        var shiftPres=0;    shiftPres=evt.shiftKey;
             altPres  =evt.altKey;
             ctrlPres =evt.ctrlKey;
             self.status=""
              +  "shiftKey="+shiftPres 
              +", altKey="  +altPres 
              +", ctrlKey=" +ctrlPres        if (shiftPressed)
            {       /**some data**/             }  } }

Comment: @Joker : Please post your full code. If possible create a jsfiddle.

Comment: it works only in firefox exactly what i want..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this snippet (tested: working on Chrome and Firefox):

```js
function copyToClipboard(text) {
    var $temp = $('<input>');
    $('body').append($temp);
    $temp.val(text).select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    $temp.remove();
}

$(function($) {
    var ctrlDown = false;
    var ctrlKey = 17;
    var cmdKey = 91;
    var cKey = 67;

    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        // if (CTRL + C)
        if (ctrlDown && (e.keyCode == cKey)) {
            copyToClipboard(selection.join(' '));
            selection = [];
            return false;
        }
        if (e.keyCode == ctrlKey || e.keyCode == cmdKey) {
            ctrlDown = true;
        }
    }).keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == ctrlKey || e.keyCode == cmdKey) {
            ctrlDown = false;
        }
    });

    var selection = [];
    $('#tbl1 td').dblclick(function() {
        selection.push(this.innerHTML);
        $('#copyingText').val(selection.join(', '));
    });
});
```

```css
td {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #555;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="tbl1" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>first</td>
        <td>second</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>third</td>
        <td>4th</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5th</td>
        <td>6th</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<hr>
<input type="text" id="copyingText" value="">
<input type="text" placeholder="paste text here">
```

References:

- [Detect CTRL+c.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2904944/6188402)
- [Trigger CTRL+c.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30905277/6188402)

Comment: Glad to see it worked now.. Any questions, feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding event listner for double click like this

```
 srcBox.addEventListener("dblclick", hiLite, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.dblclick()` to achieve this ( https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/ ). Then just use jQuery to select what you need.

Comment: dblclick working properly.. but the problem is i couldn't select "second" , "third" and "5th" at a time.