# How to listen Control-C pressed? (Server Closing not Copy at client side)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I want to do some clean up works when Control-C is pressed? How to achieve that in a Asp .Net Core Web Api App?

I simply want to write some logging messages to a text file when the app is closing.

Comment: asp.net is for web apps..  did you mean a .net core console app?

Comment: It is not at all clear what you're wanting to do or why.  Please provide more detail.

Comment: You cannot achive this with `Asp.NET Core` or with any other `Asp.NET` frameworks. `Control - C` is obviosly keyboard input. So you need to achive this on client side - javascript maybe

Comment: @Fabio, I don't mean Ctrl-C(Copy) at client side, but Ctrl-C at server side to interrupt the process. Is there a way to listen for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can register a function to be invoked by ASP.NET Core when the application exits (via `Ctrl-C` on the console) via `IApplicationService.ApplicationStopping` in `Startup.cs`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    ....
    var applicationLifetime = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IApplicationLifetime>();
    applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnShutdown);
    ....
}

private void OnShutdown()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Goodbye!");
}
```

When you run this (using `dotnet run`):

```
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

Enter `Ctrl-C` and you should see:

```
^CGoodbye!
```

Answer (score -3):

Because ASP.NET Core is for websites, you can do this with jQuery for example.

See: [How to detect Ctrl+V, Ctrl+C using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903991/how-to-detect-ctrlv-ctrlc-using-javascript)

Comment: I don't mean detect Ctrl-C at client side. I mean Ctrl-C at server side, which closes the ASP.NET App.