# VueJS - How to detect Ctrl+V?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, textinput

I've already seen the answers to **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2903991/2562819)**, but it's not the solution I need, since it's for **jQuery**, and I need something for **vue.js**.

So far, I was able to detect single character presses using the ff. code:

```js
export default {
  name: 'game',

  data () {
    return {
      allowInput: false,
      disabledKeys: ['ArrowLeft', 'Home', 'Control']
    }
  },

  methods: {
    keymonitor: function (event) {
      console.log(event.key)
      
      if (this.disabledKeys.indexOf(event.key) >= 0) {
        event.preventDefault()
        this.allowInput = false
        // alert('not allowed')
      } else {
        this.allowInput = true
      }
    },

    checkAnswer () {
      if (! this.allowInput) {
        alert('the key(s) you pressed is/are not allowed')
      }
    } /* END checkAnswer */
  } /* END methods */
} /* END export default */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.2/vue.min.js"></script>

<input id="typeBox" ref="typeBox" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Type here..."
       @keydown="keymonitor" @keyup="checkAnswer()" />
```

The code above successfully prevents the textbox from accepting <kbd>ArrowLeft</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd>, and <kbd>Control</kbd> key presses.

**The problem:**

I'm trying to figure out how to detect <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, because I want to prevent paste action in my text box. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check the snippet, you are using exports in it :)

Comment: The same approach can be used as in the answer you referenced. Just use `document.addEventListener` instead of jQuery methods.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903991/how-to-detect-ctrlv-ctrlc-using-javascript Here's the answare usying keyup and keydown events

Comment: @Amresh I am aware that it is throwing an error in the snippet "tool" here, but it doesn't have any error in my dev environment right now.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To detect two keys, Vue provides [modifier keys](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Modifier-Keys), For example to detect <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, you can simply do:

```
<input @keyup.alt.67="YourFn">
```

Similarly for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, you can do:

```
<input @keyup.ctrl.76="YourFn">
```

As I can see [here](http://www.physics.udel.edu/%7Ewatson/scen103/ascii.html), ASCII code for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> is 22, so you should be simply able to do :

```
<input @keyup.22="YourFn">
```

Comment: As much as I like this answer there is a [note](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Modifier-Keys) that says: ...keyup.ctrl will only trigger if you release a key while holding down ctrl. It won’t trigger if you release the ctrl key alone.

Comment: This works like magic! I can even use it alongside my existing `@keyup`/`@keydown` functions. `@keydown.22` doesn't do anything, so I used `@keydown.ctrl.86` instead. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

you can check the js fiddle link for the same

```
keyup: function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 86 && event.ctrlKey){
    // do something here
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/neelkansara28/wh61rby8/16/

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little late to the party here but for anyone coming here with this same question, there is really no need for anything fancy that is not built into Vue itself. If you don't want to read through all of this

[Here is a sandbox with a working example to play with](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-prevent-paste-mtkzrs?file=/src/components/Playground.vue:299-712)

As the accepted answer says, vue has it's own event listeners as [documented here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Modifier-Keys)

It also does not require key codes, specifically, to work. So in your case, it will accept the letter `v`

Below is an example of a vuetify component (although this will work with pretty much any element):

```
<v-text-field
   v-model="textField"
   @keydown.prevent.ctrl.v=""
   @keydown.prevent.meta.v=""
   @click.prevent.right.exact=""
/>
```

Here is the breakdown of the `@stuff` that you see there:

- To prevent key combos like `ctrl/cmd` + `v`:

  - In the case of combos, in order to make it work, you'll have to listen to `keydown` instead of the alternatives
  - To account for Windows, you'll need to use `@keydown.prevent.ctrl.v=""`
  - To account for Mac, you'll need to use `@keydown.prevent.meta.v=""`
  - `@keydown` listens for the keydown event
  - `.prevent` automatically applies `event.preventDefault()`
  - `.ctrl/.meta` are the modifier keys you're listening for

    - the `meta` key is the `CMD` key on Mac and `Windows` key on Windows
  - `v` is, of course, the other key we are listening for
  - the empty `""` just means we're not giving it a function to run. if you want to do anything additional, you can just simply reference a function here. like: `@keydown.prevent.meta.v="doSomethingElse"`
- **If you *also* want to prevent the right-click (context) menu**: `@click.prevent.right.exact=""`

  - `@click` will listen to the click event.
  - `.right` is the modifier to listen for right-clicks only
  - `.exact` makes sure that no other modifiers are accepted. Without this, someone could press `shift` + `right-click` and the context menu would appear as normal. In this case, `.exact` makes sure we're doing something on any version of `right-click`