# I get ASCII code 10 instead of 13 when I press <CTRL> + m

Tags: javascript

I expect the result is 13. but the browser console give me
`{
  "altKey": false,
  "ctrlKey": true,
  "shiftKey": false,
  "char": undefined,
  "charCode": 10,
  "key": "Enter",
  "keyCode": 10
}`

why 10 , is it normal?  it show 10 too if I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>

```js
$('body').keypress(
    ({altKey,ctrlKey,shiftKey,char,charCode,key,keyCode})=>
        console.log({altKey,ctrlKey,shiftKey,char,charCode,key,keyCode})
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: See this answer to a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2904944/1532004 note: the solution is the same, just check for keycode m instead of c or v.

Answer (score 0):

Check just for the value of 13 in `event.keyCode`.

```js
$('body').keypress((event) => {
    if (event.ctrlKey && event.key === 'm') {
      console.log("ctrl+m pressed");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: event.keyCode === 13 is for Enter key not for ctrl+m

Comment: hmm, "ctrl+m" and "enter" were both generating a keyCode of 13 in my browser, but you're right, that's ambiguous, I've updated my code snippet with improved code, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

check below code 77 keycode for "m"

```
function KeyPress(e) {
      var evtobj = window.event? event : e
      console.log(evtobj.keyCode);
      if (evtobj.keyCode == 77 && evtobj.ctrlKey) alert("Ctrl+m");
}

document.onkeydown = KeyPress;
```