# How to show blinking text cursor/caret in a read-only div

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I show a blinking cursor (allowing for text selection via keyboard) in a div but keep it read-only (disallowing text input)?

I know I can set `contentEditable` to enable the cursor on a div but then users can edit the contents. I've tried adding both `contentEditable` and `readonly` to the div but it seems `readonly` is only effective on input elements, like textarea or input.

I also have tried using a textarea and setting it to readonly so it shows the cursor but doesn't allow text input, like this:

```html
<textarea readonly>Go ahead and move the cursor here but don't try to add text</textarea>
```

This is the functionality I'm looking for but I want to do this with a div or some other non-input element. I'm open to using 3rd party libraries.

---

**Note:** "Cursor" or "caret" here is referring to the blinking lines that indicates where text selection starts/ends.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go :) . All you need to do is disable cut/copy/paste and key press events.

```html
<div
  contenteditable="true"
  oncut="return false"
  onpaste="return false"
  onkeydown="return false;"
  style="user-drag: none;"
  ondragenter="return false;" 
  ondragleave="return false;" 
  ondragover="return false;" 
  ondrop="return false;">
  Inner content
</div>
```

Comment: This is basically what I am looking for but it disables text selection. For that I guess I'd have to dig into the onkeydown event and make sure it doesn't preventDefault when the user hits the arrow keys or shift. This seems like a good solution.

Comment: to actually detect and allow `ctrl+c` you can use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2904944/8397816)

Comment: @BradyDowling Can you please accept the answer if it served the purpose.

Comment: I still can edit the content. Select the text and move it (drag-drop) to another part of the sentence.

Comment: Also, inline-JS is a bad habit and can even raise `unsafe-inline` flags. `addEventListener` should be used towards separation of concerns.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan fixed drag and drop issue.  and i added inline JS just for the sake of code brewity. but it doesn't deserve downvote. no?

Answer (score 0):

In Vanilla JavaScript, This is the simplest example of how you can go about doing it. I am using a class here, but as other answers showed, you could change it to an actual attribute or whatever suits your linking.

```js
  const uneditables = Array.from(
        document.querySelectorAll(".editable-but-not-really")
  );

  const doNothing = e => e.preventDefault();

  uneditables.forEach(element => {
    element.setAttribute("contentEditable", true);
    element.addEventListener("oncut", doNothing, false);
    element.addEventListener("onpaste", doNothing, false);
    element.addEventListener("keydown", doNothing, false);
  });
```

```html
<div class="editable-but-not-really">I am here to stay</div>
<div class="editable-but-not-really">You cannot edit me</div>
<div class="editable-but-not-really">I was born to stay</div>
<div class="editable-but-not-really">As I am, and I don't</div>
<div class="editable-but-not-really">want anything to do with</div>
<div class="editable-but-not-really">your stinky pointer</div>
```