# JS - Is there a way to display clipboard text?

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard

I'm working on a school assignment where I'm attempting to increase the visibility of `Ctrl + c` and `Ctrl + p`. My goal, right now, is to show what text has been copied in a second `textarea`. The code I have 'works' but it's not ideal.

Here is my code (which I have gotten from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903991/how-to-detect-ctrlv-ctrlc-using-javascript) and [here](https://alligator.io/js/async-clipboard-api/)):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Ctrl+c Ctrl+v allowed</h3>
<textarea></textarea>
<br>
<br>
<h3>Clipboard</h3>
<textarea id="clipBoard"></textarea>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var ctrlDown = false,
            ctrlKey = 17,
            cmdKey = 91,
            vKey = 86,
            cKey = 67;

        $(document).keydown(function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == ctrlKey || e.keyCode == cmdKey) ctrlDown = true;
        }).keyup(function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == ctrlKey || e.keyCode == cmdKey) ctrlDown = false;
        });     

        // Document Ctrl + C/V 
        $(document).keydown(function(e) {

            var clip = document.getElementById("clipBoard");
            if (ctrlDown && (e.keyCode == cKey))
            {
                navigator.clipboard.readText()
                .then(text => {
                    clip.value = text;
                })
                .catch(err => {

                });
                console.log("Document catch Ctrl+C");

            }
            if (ctrlDown && (e.keyCode == vKey)) 
            {
                console.log("Document catch Ctrl+V");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

There are 2 problems with this solution.

First, the webpage asks for permission to copy. I understand the need for this, but is there a way to get around this?

Second, if a user says no then I can't display the clipbaord text when there is something in the clipboard which would just ruin the assignment.

Is there a way to get around these problems?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No. You can use older technologies like `execCommand` to paste the clipboard contents into a focused textbox, but that requires actually pasting it and is outdated. The modern Clipboard API requires user permission for a very good reason (imagine if you copied, say, a porn URL or a bank account number, and a website could get that info without anyone knowing) -- trying to bypass permission requirements for APIs that require it is not good. If this is for a school assignment, I see no reason your teacher or whoever is grading you wouldn't give the browser permission to use the Clipboard API when they've asked you to get clipboard contents.

Comment: Ya I totally understand the purpose for permission. This is a UI class, so I would have permission to the clipboard but I have to account for the user pressing no or being annoyed by the prompt every time. This is unfortunate, might have to pick something else for this assignment. Thanks though!

Comment: If the user presses No, it means they don't want you reading their clipboard; you can `.catch` that on the end of your promise chain and show a message like "You said we can't read your clipboard, so this app will not function. Sorry." or something.

Comment: Is there a way I can get permission just once and display clipboard data from then on?

Comment: That's how it should already work, until you reload the page or go to a different URL.

Comment: Oh really? Right now it's prompting me every time I press `Ctrl + c`

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome

Comment: Are you running the page locally (i.e. with the `file://` protocol instead of, for instance, `http://`)? If so, that's why; local files don't remember permissions. If you run it from a server (even a local server like VSCode's Live Server extension), it will remember after the first time.

Comment: I am running the code locally because I have to hand it in in a format that anyone can access it from anywhere (annoying hand in requirements). Can I achieve this locally?

Comment: If you want it to remember permissions, it needs to be on a server. If you can't be sure the user can host it on their own local server, you'll need to put it on a web host somewhere and give them the URL.