# Is it possible to set a shortcut with js or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + right arrow,

I want the following code to run:

```
alert ('ctr | + right');
```

I tried to implement it using js logic, but it was difficult.

Thanks for letting me know

my code

```
$(function() {
    $('body').keydown(function(e) {
       if(e.ctrlKey && e.which == 78 ){
            alert('ctrㅣ + n');
       }
    });
});
```

It was a conflict with the chrome shortcut.
Thanks to those who answered I solved the problem
Thanks for the hint.

this code is work
39 is right direction key

```
$(function() {
  $('body').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.which === 39) {
      alert('ctrㅣ + n');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: If you show the javascript code you tried, it will be easier for people to show you where you went wrong.

Comment: If you've tried to implement it already, could you post the code you've got? This will give people something to work on and help you.

Comment: Take a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903991/how-to-detect-ctrlv-ctrlc-using-javascript

Comment: Thanks for the link, maybe I can do it with the link

Comment: No way to override Ctrl + N in Chrome since it opens a new window and can no longer be intercepted by the client side JavaScript in the web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `78` with `69`. Also in major browser <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> is shortcut for creating new document

```js
$(function() {
  $('body').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.which === 69) {
      alert('ctrㅣ + n');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It was a conflict with the chrome shortcut.

I solved the problem with a hint on how you told me.

Comment: Looks like you solved your problem - also want to mention if you are able to add an additional dependency, mousetrap js is really easy to use for this type of functionality. https://github.com/ccampbell/mousetrap

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('body').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.which === 69) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('ctrㅣ + n');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Except from `e.preventDefault();` how is your answer different from thet answers that has already been posted.

Comment: that's it...e.preventDefault()... it tries to stop the default browser action, so the other piece of code can run...that's the solution!

Comment: It was a conflict with the chrome shortcut.

I solved the problem with a hint on how you told me. thanks